# Django trying to split a user's email to display in a template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to split a user's email to just the domain and display it on the front end. I'm using Django's user model.

models.py

```
class UserDomain(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def splitEmailToDomain(self):
        return self.user.email.split('@')[1].lower()
```

index.html

```
<input type="text" value="{{UserDomain.splitEmailToDomain}}">
```

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? You need to provide some context of the function `splitEmailToDomain`, there are too many questions by eyeballing the code, like what does `self.join()` do? What does the context of views.py function look like? What's `{{ UserDomain }}` in the template? A class or an object?

Comment: @ShangWang good for you deleting your last comment, it was rude.

Comment: Consider a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) instead of a model method for trivial tasks like this.

Comment: @ShangWang `self.join` will call `UserDomain.__str__` to get a string and then insert that between the output of `user.email.split`

Comment: @ShangWang it's not displaying anything in the value attribute. I'm using the join method to stitch back my split string. I've got context = RequestContext(request) in my views.py but is it related to the output?

Comment: @kdopen: That doesn't make any sense, I don't realize that `models.Model` has a method called `join`

Comment: It doesn't, but it *does* have a __str__ method (even if only inherited) and `join` is a method of `str`. I'm assuming some implicit conversion, but it wouldn't surprise me if it worked

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. `str(self).join(...)` would work. I think the OP was trying to come up with a minimal example and just missed some stuff. I switch between so many languages in a typical week sometimes they blur together

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define it as a property, and apply `join` to an empty string:

```
class UserDomain(models.Model):
    @property
    def splitEmailToDomain(self):
        return ''.join(self.user.email.split('@')[1]).lower()
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, am I doing something wrong with the template tag instead?

Comment: Where are you getting from `user.email`? Is `user` a field in your `UserDomain` model? If so, I edited my answer. And if possible show your model fields.

Comment: I'm getting `user.email` from django's user model, user is a field in my domain model: `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`

Comment: Doesn't need to be a property, any instance method will do (as long as it isn't parameterized)

Comment: @saffront So try with `self.user.email`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class actually looks something like

```
class UserDomain(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,...)
```

And your `User` class has an `email` field.

Then your method needs to be more like this:

```
   ...
    def email_domain(self):
        return self.user.email.split('@')[1].lower()
```

Then in your template you can just say

```
{{object.email_domain}}
```